# How do I change a dom node input and parse relevant information with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How do I change the dom node input and parse relevant information with Mechanize?

I want the website to show a range of trucks manufactured from 2010 upwards so I can parse the relevant information.

What I want it to do:

1. Visit https://www.kleyntrucks.com/trucks/tractorunit/
2. Set "MATRICULATION YEAR" (iow year of manufacture) to the range of 2010 and 2014 (http://d.pr/i/kDky)
3. Scrape information about all the trucks that are listed (and are manufactured between 2010 and 2014)

This is the code:

```
require "mechanize"

@url = "https://www.kleyntrucks.nl/vrachtwagens/trekker/"

a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
end

a.get(@url) do |page|

        # Put range input to "2010"
    bouwjaar_range_field = page.search("#imprp0")
    bouwjaar_range_details = bouwjaar_range_field.search(".details")
    input = bouwjaar_range_details.search("input")[0]
    input['value'] = "2010"

    puts bouwjaar_range_field

end
```

This is the output:

```
<li id="imprp0" class="">
    <a name="bouwjaar"></a>
    <div class="title">Bouwjaar</div>
    <div class="details">

                    <input type="hidden" name="slider_from" value="2010"><input type="hidden" name="slider_till" value="2014"><input type="hidden" name="slider_selected_from" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="slider_selected_till" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="slider_units" value="">
</div>
</li>
```

It does not show all the truck related information I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use Mechanize that easily because the page is using AJAX updates.

Unlike a browser, Mechanize doesn't execute any Javascript on the page, and thus doesn't update the results via AJAX when you change an input.

It's still possible to grab the results using Mechanize, but you'll have to craft the request with the necessary parameters manually (the request that is posted with AJAX; you can see it with Developer Tools), post it, and parse the result page.